# Separar una URL en sus partes

Tags: java, regex, string, url

Estoy intentando escribir un método que se llame `separarURL()`, que reciba una cadena de caracteres de una URL y devuelva un array de tres String, conteniendo el protocolo, el servidor y el recurso de la URL recibida.

Ejemplo:

> http://www.devbg.org/forum/index.php

El resultado esperado es:

```
resultado[0]: "http" 
resultado[1]: "www.devbg.org" 
resultado[2]: "/forum/index.php"
```

He estado pensando en utilizar una expresión separar los elementos (protocolo, servidor y recurso de la URL) y utilizar el método split para separar la URL en partes y así poder introducir cada parte en el array de String final, pero no se como plantearlo.
La expresión que había pensado es esta:

```
String exp = "(http)|(://)|(/)";
```

pero no estoy seguro de que sea muy correcta.

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano con ello?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. Con [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)**

La clase [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) ya lo hace sin que tengas que reinventar la rueda, incluso sirve para validarla:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
```

```
String prueba = "http://www.devbg.org:8080/forum/index.php?busq=abc#sec1";
try{
    URL miUrl = new URL(prueba);
    System.out.println("protocolo = " + miUrl.getProtocol());
    System.out.println("autoridad = " + miUrl.getAuthority());
    System.out.println("dominio   = " + miUrl.getHost());
    System.out.println("puerto    = " + miUrl.getPort());
    System.out.println("ruta      = " + miUrl.getPath());
    System.out.println("búsqueda  = " + miUrl.getQuery());
    System.out.println("archivo   = " + miUrl.getFile());
    System.out.println("ancla     = " + miUrl.getRef());
}catch(MalformedURLException ex){
    System.out.println("URL inválida");
}
```

Resultado:

```
protocolo = http
autoridad = www.devbg.org:8080
dominio   = www.devbg.org
puerto    = 8080
ruta      = /forum/index.php
búsqueda  = busq=abc
archivo   = /forum/index.php?busq=abc
ancla     = sec1
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/ZLBH4a

---

**2. Con regex**

Pero si te interesa reinventar la rueda (aunque no tiene sentido), en vez de buscar separar el string, lo mejor es crear una expresión regular que *coincida* con cada una de las partes, capturando lo que nos interesa con cada paréntesis:

```
^(?:([^:]*):(?://)?)?([^/]*)(/.*)?
```

- `^` ≝ Inicio del texto
- `(?:([^:]*):(?://)?)?` ≝ Parte opcional:

  - `([^:]*)` ≝ ***Grupo 1*** (protocolo) - todos los caracteres que no sean `:`
  - `:` ≝ seguidos de `:`
  - `(?://)?` - opcionalmente las `//` del inicio
- `([^/]*)` ≝ ***Grupo 2*** (host) - todos los caracteres que no sean `/`
- `(/.*)?` ≝ ***Grupo 3*** opcional (ruta):

  - `/` ≝ una barra
  - `.*` ≝ seguida de cualquier cantidad de caracteres

Si el regex coincide cuando usamos [Matcher.find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), el texto que coincidió con cada par de paréntesis lo obtenemos con [Matcher.group(n)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-).

Código:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
```

```
String prueba = "http://www.devbg.org/forum/index.php";

//Variables para el regex
final String regex = "^(?:([^:]*):(?://)?)?([^/]*)(/.*)?";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(prueba);

//Ver si coincide el regex
if (matcher.find()) {
    //Obtener el texto capturado por cada conjunto de paréntesis
    String protocolo = matcher.group(1);
    String dominio   = matcher.group(2);
    String ruta      = matcher.group(3);

    System.out.println("protocolo = " + protocolo);
    System.out.println("dominio   = " + dominio);
    System.out.println("ruta      = " + ruta);
}
```

Resultado:

```
protocolo = http
dominio   = www.devbg.org
ruta      = /forum/index.php
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/hVUq3e

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar el método [String.Split](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) para separarlos. Puedes marcar el límite del número de barras que quieres llegar a cortar:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String string = "http://www.devbg.org/forum/index.php"; String[] parts = string.split("//");

String domain=parts[1].split("/")[0];
//aquí es donde debes decir que corte menos de 2 para que cuente todo
String suburl=parts[1].split("/", 2)[1];

System.out.println(domain); System.out.println(suburl);

    } }
```

Aquí puedes ver cómo funciona

https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler#&togetherjs=zHHRyKifo9

Answer (score 0):

Esta bien, pero yo usaría está

```
(http(|s)):\/\/(.*)\/(.*)
```

En el grupo 1 tenés el protocolo
En el grupo 2 el dominio
Y en el grupo 3 la ruta